# Multiple seasonal ARIMA modelling in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics

I'm looking for a way to specify two or more seasonalities in ARIMA model in Matlab.
For example I'd like to be able to do this :

arimaMdl = arima('D',1,'ARLags',[1:3],'MALags',[1:3],'SMALags',[24,24*7],'Seasonality',[24,24*7]);

To specify a 24h seasonality and a week seasonality.
When I try this, it says that the seasonality parameter accepts only a scalar argument.
Is there another way to do it with Matlab please?